# Calling function on enter press on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, function, jsfiddle, enter

So far I have this function to call my search when enter is pressed:

```
$("#query").keypress(function(e) {
if(e.which == 13) {
    alert('You pressed enter!');
    redditsearch();
}
});
```

I'm getting the alert, but it gives me an error:

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': 
u'initial-js_lib', 'form':         <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 
0x3787b50>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 
'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x318ab50>,     
'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 
'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x3787b50>,
'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap',
'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x270b510>, 'help_text': '',
'name':       'js_wrap'}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try preventing the default behaviour of the enter keypress:

```
$("#query").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('You pressed enter!');
        redditsearch();
    }
});
```

Without this, if your input is within a form, the form will be submitted along with your search function called. The preventDefault stops the default form submission behaviour.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I've also noticed that in my code I have to click the submit button twice, and now i have to hit enter twice for my script to run. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: I wouldn't know without seeing the relevant code. It's probably worth you raising another question for that issue and providing your HTML and Javascript code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/elliotmersch/BmL4M/ Here's my fiddle if you think you could lend a hand. I'll create another post as well. Appreciate it

Comment: It is because your code for clicking on "hide" buttons is causing errors. Look into adding click events to dynamically generated content using the jQuery "on" method.

Comment: Ah, you're right. It works without that code in there now. I can't figure out how to make each hide button unique to that specific comment. I have it set up to do button1, button2, button3, etc. until end of comments, but idk how to write one looped function to hide comments besides writing a specific function for every single button

Comment: Raise a question for it, provide that JSFiddle and you'll get some help, it's difficult to do this stuff in the comments ;)